# Issue trying to customizing the admin in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, customization

In order to add some links in the admin of my site I added a custom block (surrounded in red in the images below) to admin/base.html and set it in admin/base_site.html.

The issue is that it's shown in all admin pages (eg connexion screenshot shown below), while I'd like to show it only in the site admin first page.

Anybody could help?

**admin/base.html**

```
...

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content" class="{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}">
    {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
    {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}
    {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}

    {% block myblock %}{% endblock %} <!-- custom block -->

    <br class="clear" />
</div>
<!-- END Content -->

....
```

**admin/base_site.html**

```
....

{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Administration de Django' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
{% block myblock %}
    <div style="margin-top:160px;">
    <div style="font-size:18px; color:#666666;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:10px;">Rapports</div>
        <a href="/rapports_journaliers/">Rapports journaliers</a><br/>
        <a href="/rapports_mensuels/">Rapports mensuels</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

....
```

**Site admin**

[image]

**Connexion**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you are better off overriding admin/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I would like to recommend to you [django-admin-tools](https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/wiki/Home) application. As documentation says:

> **django-admin-tools** is a collection of extensions/tools for the default
>   django administration interface, it includes:
>
> - a full featured and customizable dashboard;
> - a customizable menu bar;
> - tools to make admin theming easier. 
>     Please join the mailing list if you want to discuss of the future of django-admin-tools.